# Recursive algorithm complexity analysis

Tags: c++, complexity-theory

I am trying to analyze the complexity of this algorithm but I am not sure if its recurrence equation is T (n / 2) + 2n, could you help me? size of v > 100

```cpp
bool pareado(int v[], int left, int right) {
    bool b;
    if (left >= right)
        b = true;
    else {
        int m = (left + right) / 2;
        bool baux = (abs(contarPares(v, left, m) - contarPares(v, m + 1, right)) <= 1);
        if (baux == false)
            b = false;
        else
            b = pareado(v, left, m) && pareado(v, m + 1, right);
    }
    return b;
}
```

The function "contarPares" is this:

```cpp
int contarPares(int v[], int i, int j) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int k = i; k <= j; k++) {
        if ((v[k] % 2) == 0)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: @AlexGuteniev The point is that iterator pairs would make this algorithm much clearer. So, having two std::array<int,N>::const_iterator objects would go a long way. Even two clearly named `int const*` parameters would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pareado` function has complexity O(n) [ for n = right-left ] **before** recursing. Given that on each recursion step you partition your input range, and handle them separately, you still have to iterate over the entire range once (for any iteration depth) in the worst case.

How many recursion depths are there? In the worst case you must wait until `contarPares` returns `0` because it has no input left, i.e. its range is empty. Given that you **always** half your input range, this will take log(n) recursions.

Since each depth costs O(n) and you have O(log(n)) depths, you come down to a total of **O(n*log(n))**.

Of course depending on your input array, you may terminate much earlier, but you won't exceed the limit given above.